# How to set custom PHP.ini

Tags: php

The *loaded configuration file* path is `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` (found using `phpinfo();`).

How can I edit this file or making a copy of this file anywhere I wish? In some forums I was asked to execute this command,

`cp /usr/local/lib/php.ini /public_html` so that the PHP.ini file will be copied to public_html folder. But I do not understand where to execute this command.

I do not have much idea in PHP, so that I could resolve this issue on my own. What is the detailed procedure to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you have access to your own dedicated server or virtual machine:**

Open up the terminal, type `sudo nano /usr/local/lib/php.ini`,
make the required changes, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

If you want to copy to somewhere else, use `cp /usr/local/lib/php.ini /path/to/new/location`

**If you are using a shared hosting provider**

You *can not* modify the *php.ini* file or use another version. You will need to override the settings in the `.htaccess` file or a PHP runtime. Please note that your shared host may have these settings disabled, so you can't hog the shared server's RAM.

#### File *.htaccess* example

```
php_value memory_limit 16M
```

#### Runtime example (at the very top of the PHP script)

```php
ini_set('memory_limit', '16M');
```

Comment: @whistlergereg. i think he also wan't know how use this terminal stuff

Comment: What is terminal actually? I am new to PHP. Where I can I find the terminal?

Comment: are you on a hosting provider or your local machine?

Comment: Hosting Provider using Linux OS.

Comment: mochahost.com is the hosting provider

Comment: chances are you can't change their php.ini file unless you have access to SSH into the system (if shared hosting then no chance) you can however override some setting in your .htaccess file. What do you need to do exactly?

Comment: I need to change memory_limit parameter. While inquiring with the hosting provider team he asked me to SET a custom PHP.ini file. But i dont know how to do that.

Comment: if it's a shared hosting plan you absolutely will not be able to change or set a custom php.ini file - it's the server wide settings. What you can do however is put the following in your .htaccess file `php_value memory_limit 16M` where 16M is the limit you want. There is a chance that the host may also have this disabled as you could essentially create a memory hogging script that kills all the other sites on the same machine.

Comment: @whistlergreg I was instructed to set a custom PHP.ini file by the hosting Provider

Comment: Unless you can ssh into your dedicated or virtual machine then it is 100% not possible. You can override the setting in .htaccess or at runtime (as the other answer says) but that is your only option. The support guy at the host has you on the wrong track.

Comment: I created a file named .htaccess with the following line php_value memory_limit 512M. Now it says 500 Internal server error

Comment: speak to your host. If you have a script that required 512m of memory you should not be on shared hosting. Take a look at their VPS plans which will allow you full control of your php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change most ini settings at runtime. Here is an example of changing `memory_limit`. Just use `ini_get_all()` to get the array of all the settings and there value, find the value you want changed, and then use `ini_set()`. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's end:

```
<?PHP
// before...
print_r(ini_get_all());
/**
 * Array
  (
        ...
        [memory_limit] => Array
            (
                [global_value] => 128M
                [local_value] => 128M
                [access] => 7
            )
        ...
  )
 */

// Set the new value
ini_set('memory_limit', '16M');

// after...
print_r(ini_get_all());
/**
 * Array
   (
       ...
       [memory_limit] => Array
           (
               [global_value] => 128M
               [local_value] => 16M
               [access] => 7
           )
      ...
  )
 */
```

This is also dependent on permissions allowed by your host.